# Windows 8 - in app browser (inAppBrowser) Vs browser from dekstop

Tags: browser, windows-8, inappbrowser

What's the diferrence between using the browser from app and the browser from desktop..?
one difference that i noticed is that in browser from app, the youtube stops playing when i "minimize" the window...
any other?
thank you!

Comment: There are too many, you can't ask list questions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Store Apps 'suspend' when minimized by design, but when resumed it will re-activate. This is a battery saving feature I believe (it also stops any CPU usage from the app in most cases). The desktop apps are basically windows 7. Here is a link to a page discussing the life cycle of a store app.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx